# Use the fact that $P \# K \cong3 P$ to show that $kP \#nT \cong mP$ for some $m$, as long as $k>0$.

Tags: general-topology

Use the fact that $P \# K \cong3 P$ to show that $kP \#nT \cong mP$  for some $m$, as long as $k>0$. Express $m$ as a function of $k$ and $n$. Here $P$ denotes projective plane, $T$ denotes torus.

I already proved that when n odd$$kP=(\frac{k-1}{2})T \#P$$  and when $n$ is even $$kP=(\frac{k-2}{2})T \# K$$ When $k$ is odd, I obtain $kP \#nT \cong (\frac{k-1}{2})T \#P \# nT \cong [\frac{k-1+2n}{2}]T \#P$

I stuck at here. Can anyone give some hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that when $k=3$ your formula yields $T\#P=3P$.  Now, with a sum of multiple copies of $T$ and $P$, any $T$ can be replaced by $2P$, assuming there are any $P$ to begin with.  Therefore, you get
$$kP+nT=(k+2n)P.$$